# How to render the HTML into react component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to render the pure HTML coming from some external source into react component. I saw few solutions where people are talking about some conversion tools (HTML to JSX) but I want to handle everything in my component so while mounting it will get the HTML response and that needs to render.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) for this:

```
function createMarkup() { return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'}; };
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

But as the method name suggests: you should be very sure of what you are doing there and the security implications it has.

Comment: Yup.. if you dont know the source never use. If someone embeds a malicious  Javacript inside html and you call that API, there can be consequences

Comment: I am using 'react-HTML-parser' which rendering HTML into reactJS component properly but now I am facing another issue. It requires HTML as a string and I am not sure how to stringify HTML?                     Example: I want '<div>Hello</div> instead of <div>Hello</div>

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be difficult to do . Assign your HTML to a div and then render it using `{variable name}` JSX allows you to do this and with ES6 integration you can also use `class` instead of `className`.

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
  
  render: function() {
  var htmlDiv = <div>How are you</div>
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}
      {htmlDiv}
    </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: This only works with predefined elements, not with a HTML string coming from an external source.